# Aspnet Boilerplate and Vue

Tags: vue.js, aspnetboilerplate

I am using the version v8.x of the aspnetboilerplate, including login, register, etc. I have created a new simple entity and that is working fine. Now, I am trying to get the details of a child. For example, I have the entity Organization and I would like to the display a list of organization center when editing an organization item. So, I have the corresponding edit-organization component being called like this from the organization component:
     `<edit-organization v-model="editModalShow" @save-success="getpage"></edit-organization>`
The edit-organization is the following:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <Modal
         :title="L('EditOrganization')"
         :value="value"
         @on-ok="save"
         @on-visible-change="visibleChange"
        >
            <Form ref="organizationForm"  label-position="top" :rules="organizationRule" :model="organization">
                <Tabs value="detail">
                    <TabPane :label="L('OrganizationDetails')" name="detail">
                        <FormItem :label="L('Name')" prop="name">
                            <Input v-model="organization.name" :maxlength="32"></Input>
                        </FormItem>
                    </TabPane>
                    <TabPane :label="L('OrganizationCenters')" name="organizationCenters">
                    <div class="margin-top-10">
                        <Table :loading="loading" :columns="columns" :no-data-text="L('NoDatas')" border :data="centers">
                        </Table>
                    </div>
                    </TabPane>
                </Tabs>
            </Form>
            <div slot="footer">
                <Button @click="cancel">{{L('Cancel')}}</Button>
                <Button @click="save" type="primary">{{L('OK')}}</Button>
            </div>
        </Modal>
    </div>
</template>
<script lang="ts">
    import { Component, Vue,Inject, Prop,Watch } from 'vue-property-decorator';
    import Util from '../../lib/util'
    import AbpBase from '../../lib/abpbase'
    import Orgnization from '../../store/entities/organization'
import Organization from '@/store/entities/organization';
    @Component
    export default class EditOrganization extends AbpBase{
        @Prop({type:Boolean,default:false}) value:boolean;
        organization:Organization= new Orgnization();
        get loading(){
          return this.$store.state.organization.loading;
        }
        columns=[{
          title:this.L('Name'),
          key:'name'
      }]
      get centers(){
        console.log('getting centers')
          return this.$store.state.organization.centers;
      };
       async created(){
        await this.$store.dispatch({
                        type:'organization/getCenters',
                        data:this.organization.id
                    });
        }
        save(){
            (this.$refs.organizationForm as any).validate(async (valid:boolean)=>{
                if(valid){
                    await this.$store.dispatch({
                        type:'organization/update',
                        data:this.organization
                    });
                    (this.$refs.organizationForm as any).resetFields();
                    this.$emit('save-success');
                    this.$emit('input',false);
                }
            })
        }
        cancel(){
            (this.$refs.organizationForm as any).resetFields();
            this.$emit('input',false);
        }
        visibleChange(value:boolean){
            if(!value){
                this.$emit('input',value);
            }else{
                this.organization=Util.extend(true,{},this.$store.state.organization.editOrganization);
            }
        }
        organizationRule={
            name:[{required:true,message:this.L('FieldIsRequired',undefined,this.L('Name')),trigger: 'blur'}]
        }
    }
</script>
```

How can I display the organization centers of this organization? The module organization.ts looks like this:

```
import {Store,Module,ActionContext} from 'vuex'
import ListModule from './list-module'
import ListState from './list-state'
import Organization from '../entities/organization'
import Ajax from '../../lib/ajax'
import PageResult from '@/store/entities/page-result';
import ListMutations from './list-mutations'
import OrganizationCenter from '../entities/organizationCenter'

interface OrganizationState extends ListState<Organization>{
    editOrganization:Organization;
    centers:Array<OrganizationCenter>
}
class OrganizationMutations extends ListMutations<Organization>{

}
class OrganizationModule extends ListModule<OrganizationState,any,Organization>{
    state={
        totalCount:0,
        currentPage:1,
        pageSize:10,
        list: new Array<Organization>(),
        loading:false,
        editOrganization:new Organization(),
        centers: new Array<OrganizationCenter>()
    }
    actions={
        async getAll(context:ActionContext<OrganizationState,any>,payload:any){
            context.state.loading=true;
            let reponse=await Ajax.get('/api/services/app/Organizations/GetAll',{params:payload.data});
            context.state.loading=false;
            let page=reponse.data.result as PageResult<Organization>;
            context.state.totalCount=page.totalCount;
            context.state.list=page.items;
        },
        async get(context:ActionContext<OrganizationState,any>,payload:any){
            let reponse=await Ajax.get('/api/services/app/Organizations/Get?Id='+payload.id);
            return reponse.data.result as Organization;
        },
        async create(context:ActionContext<OrganizationState,any>,payload:any){
            await Ajax.post('/api/services/app/Organizations/Create',payload.data);
        },
        async delete(context:ActionContext<OrganizationState,any>,payload:any){
            console.log(payload
                )
            await Ajax.delete('/api/services/app/Organizations/Delete?Id='+payload.data.id);
        },
        async update(context:ActionContext<OrganizationState,any>,payload:any){
            await Ajax.put('/api/services/app/Organizations/Update',payload.data);
        },
        async getCenters(context:ActionContext<OrganizationState,any>, payload:any){
            console.log('getting organization state center')
            console.log(payload)
            context.state.loading=true;
            let reponse=await Ajax.get('/api/services/app/Organizations/GetCenters?organizationId='+payload.id);
            context.state.loading=false;
            let page=reponse.data.result as PageResult<OrganizationCenter>;
            context.state.totalCount=page.totalCount;
            context.state.centers=page.items;
            return reponse.data.result as OrganizationCenter;
            // let reponse=await Ajax.get('/api/services/app/Role/getAllPermissions');
            // context.state.permissions=reponse.data.result.items;
        }
    };
    mutations={
        setCurrentPage(state:OrganizationState,page:number){
            state.currentPage=page;
        },
        setPageSize(state:OrganizationState,pagesize:number){
            state.pageSize=pagesize;
        },
        edit(state:OrganizationState,organization:Organization){
            state.editOrganization=organization;
        }
    }
}
const organizationModule=new OrganizationModule();
export default organizationModule;
```

I am trying to find a way to pass the organization id to the *getCenters *method from the edit-organization.
Thank you for your help, I know it might be easy but i'm decided to explore more on this template, I like it.

Thanks again!

Best regards,
Marius

I've tried adding a call to the created method but the organization id is not defined at that moment.
I expect to find a way to correctly pass the organization id to the method *getCenters*

Comment: It's not shown where getCenters is dispatched

Comment: You need to replace a regular call with a watcher, can't say how it will look with class syntax sugar you're using but basically something like `created(){ this.$watch('organization.id', id => { if (id) this.$store.dispatch(...) }, { immediate: true }) }`